# Iterate over a list with dynamic names

Tags: r

I have come across a behaviour of R that I can't quite get my head around and after a while browsing older threads I am still not sure what it is that I am not getting right.

Here is a minimal example:

```
ls <- list(c(1,2), c(3,4))
names(ls) <- c("one", "two")
```

Creates a list with the the following structure:

```
$one

 1  2

$two

 3  4
```

I can access an element as:

```
ls$one
```

Which returns

```
 1  2
```

But if I try with a loop e. g.:

```
for (i in names(ls)) {
    print(ls$i)
}
```

It returns

```
NULL
NULL
```

Does someone know what is the problem? Is it some slight modification that is needed or R prefers a fundamentally different approach for solving such problems?

Comment: Try `ls[[i]]` instead of `ls$i` or use `lapply(ls, print)` or `invisible(lapply(ls, print))`

Comment: `$` does something called non-standard evaluation (to enable you to pass names such as `one` instead of characters such as `"one"` and thereby save you some typing). You can't easily programmatically pass input to functions using non-standard evaluation, they are basically convenience functions primarily intended for interactive use. Luckily R provides an alternative with standard evaluation in your case, i.e., `[[`. You may want to study`help("$")`.

Comment: Thank you it did work with ls[[i]].